# lefschetz theorem for quadrics

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, cohomology

Does there exist an analogue of Lefschetz Hyperplane Theorem for cohomology that holds for intersections with (smooth) quadrics?

Comment: If you use a Veronese map to reembed your variety, then the quadric section beomes a hyperplane section.

Comment: That's for sure! :) I should have added that, for some reason which it takes long to explain, I cannot do that Veronese-trick.

Comment: I think I'm missing a point here: isn'it it enough to know that a divisor is an hyperplane section for  SOME embedding (namely that it is  a very ample divisor) to apply Lefschetz theorem?


Comment: All you have to check for Lefschetz is that your hypersurface is an effective ample divisor...

Comment: The version of the Lefschetz Hyperplane Theorem that you want can probably be found in the book "Positivity In Algebraic Geometry" by Lazarsfeld. Unfortunately I don't have it to hand to give a more precise reference. As others have already noted, all you need is that the divisor is very ample.

Comment: A good reference is  "Stratified Morse Theory", by Goresky and Macpherson